# Is there a way to apply a refactoring script just for its side-effects?

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring, automation

I've got a library that was changed to introduce a factory method to replace a constructor (the reasons aren't important right now, in the current case it was for improved type inference mostly).

Assuming that there *is* an Eclipse refactoring script for it (so I pretty much have a nice computer-readable description of the change), is there some way to *apply* that script to a project that only *uses* that library (i.e. it only has a reference to a compiled version of the library)?

For example, I start with this simple class:

```
public class MyContainer<T> {
    private final T content;

    public MyContainer(final T content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public T getContent() {
        return content;
    }
}
```

Now I introduce a factory (without making the constructor private, but that isn't really relevant right now), the factory method looks like this:

```
public static <T> MyContainer<T> holding(T content) {
    return new MyContainer<T>(content);
}
```

When I now export a migration script it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<session version="1.0">
<refactoring comment="Introduce factory &apos;holding&apos; in &apos;scratch.MyContainer&apos; for constructor &apos;scratch.MyContainer.MyContainer()&apos;&#x0A;- Original project: &apos;scratch&apos;&#x0A;- Original element: &apos;scratch.MyContainer.MyContainer()&apos;&#x0A;- Factory name: &apos;holding&apos;&#x0A;- Owner class: &apos;scratch.MyContainer&apos;"
             description="Introduce factory for &apos;MyContainer&apos;"
             element1="/src&lt;scratch{MyContainer.java[MyContainer"
             flags="589830" id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.introduce.factory"
             input="/src&lt;scratch{MyContainer.java"
             name="holding" project="scratch" protect="false"
             selection="89 0" version="1.0"/>
</session>
```

This *should* hold enough information to apply the refactoring to another project that references (a *current* version) of the class via a jar file.

But trying to apply the refactoring gives me this error:

> The refatoring 'Introduce Factory' (org.eclipse.jdt.ui.introduce.factory) cannot be performed, since its input 'scratch.MyContainer.java' does not exist.

Note that it *explicitly* mentions `.java`, so it's looking for a source file and isn't content with applying the refactoring to the binary type.

*Note:* I *don't* want to patch the binary library. I *just* want the *callers* of the original constructor to be converted to calling the factory method instead.

*Note 2:* Search-and-replace won't help in my specific case. The reason is that I have *two* constructors, one taking an `Object` and the other takes a `String`. They should be mapped on two *different* factory methods, so I'd need the search-and-replace function to look at the type information of the argument as well.

*Note 3:* even a way to manually specify "replace instantiations of object `X` with this constructor with calls to this method instead" would be appreciated.

*Update:* There is a bugzilla entry on the Eclipse bugzilla that is about [adding a replace invocation refactoring](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=44201). An implementation of that feature *might* be able to solve my problem, if "invocation" includes object instantiation via a given constructor. Unfortunately it saw no activity in the last few years (although it was planned for 3.2).

Comment: Out of interest, is there a reason why search-and-replace won't work? Has the signature changed in such a way that it prevents you writing a (not-so-)simple string manipulation script to pull out the parameters and pass it to the factory in a couple of lines?

Comment: @Bringer128: in my case I have two constructors: one takes an `Object`, the other takes a `String`. And they would get mapped to two different factory methods (for better readability). So I'd need the type information in my search-and-replace functionality.

Comment: The only thing I can think of then is to make your own refactoring plug-in, using [IntroduceFactoryRefactoring.java](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/corext/refactoring/code/IntroduceFactoryRefactoring.java.htm) as a guide.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a way to apply refactoring to callers only but it may get you past your problem.

Would it be possible to add to your project a fake `MyContainer.java` file that has the same signatures as that in the library, apply your refactoring and then discard the java file? You could even use decompiled soure, though you might have to generify it yourself.

Comment: This is what I was currently doing ('though I'm re-executing the refactoring manually instead of applying the script), but it's definitely not perfect. In the long run I'd like to build a library of refactoring scripts to ship with a new version of the library saying "apply these and you'll be more than half-way to porting your code to the new version".

Comment: Are you going to ship the sources of the library? It seems you are applied the refactoring to the project that defines `MyContainer`. When I attempt to Introduce Factory in a project that *uses* the jar, my version of Eclipse (Build id: 20100218-1602) says *Introduce Factory is not supported when the constructor is in a binary class*.

Comment: @Hermal: In my example I don't ship the source of the factory, so that's even worse. But even for an case where you'd ship the source, you don't want the *user* to *need* to have that source. Especially since the refactoring can't be applied to the *current* version of the source (as it would introduce a method that already exists).

Comment: I am saying Eclipse refactoring does not support this at all -- Introduce Factory seems to be about adding factory method, the call-site changes seem to be a secondary refactoring caused by the first. Interesting problem though, I think I recently read about a tool in `Go` that made call-site changes to properly use new version of an API.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to write your own refactoring plugin. The [tests](http://dev.eclipse.org/viewcvs/viewvc.cgi/org.eclipse.jdt.ui.tests.refactoring/test%20cases/org/eclipse/jdt/ui/tests/refactoring/RefactoringTest.java?view=markup) for org.eclipse.jdt.ui.tests.refactoring are an interesting place to start.

Some interesting reads on the topic:

- http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Unleashing-the-Power-of-Refactoring/index.html
- http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-LTK/ltk.html