# How to automate Java code refactoring using a script with instructions?

Tags: java, refactoring, automated-refactoring

How to refactor this class programmatically via Java code/Groovy plugin?
Let's say, I need to:

- Rename `foo.method2` to `foo.method3`
- Rename `myMethod` to `yourMethod`
- Change the imported package `org.you.core.util.AnotherClassFromExternalPackage`

```
import com.me.core.util.AnotherClassFromExternalPackage;
import com.me.core.util.Foo;

public class MyClass implements AnotherClassFromExternalPackage {

    private final Foo foo;

    public MyClass() {
        this.foo = new Foo();
    }

    @Override
    public long myMethod() {
        return foo.method2();
    }
}
```

How to create a script that will parse the code, apply syntactical transformations and save it using given instructions?

The code above is just an example. The bigger problem is that I have a lot of projects that are using the same external library. And sometimes they release a new version with breaking changes that is breaking the current code after the dependency bump.
And I must update the dependency to the latest version every 2 weeks for 10+ projects. I need to write a script that will fix these breaking changes automatically.
Ideally, apply code transformations one by one.

Comment: A long time ago I [looked for something very similar for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566565/is-there-a-way-to-apply-a-refactoring-script-just-for-its-side-effects) and didn't find a good answer. It's quite possible that this thing now exists.

Comment: Well, the company I'm working for develops a rule-based refactoring engine (Eclipse plugin and Maven plugin), but it doesn't allow custom rules. It does have some for frequently used migration paths, such as between jUnit versions and various styles of Asserts: https://jsparrow.github.io/

Comment: I need exactly the same but with the custom rules :(

Comment: Get IntelliJ.  It's terrific at refactoring.  Not something I'd script.

Comment: @duffymo: indeed it is, but as a developer of libraries that others use, I want to hand them a simple way to do all the "mechanical" transformations that might be necessary to migrate to another major version of my library.

Comment: @GarrukTheWildspeaker if you have a specific migration path in mind that may also be useful to other people, feel free to use the [jsparrow contact form](https://jsparrow.io/contact-us/) to send us a feature request - it will be considered. User-customizable rules are unfortunately out of scope for now.

Comment: @JoachimSauer, if I'm a user of your library I expect to add your code as a package.  I'm certainly not going to apply any refactorings.  I expect you to do that, publish the modified package to a public repo with release notes.  I would get rid of your library if you gave me a script to apply a refactoring to your code.  I have never gotten a script to modify MY code from Spring Boot.  I don't see how it can be practical.

Comment: @duffymo: I'm not talking about applying refactoring to the library. I'm talking about the client code that *uses* the library.

Comment: Yes.  I've never seen such a thing from Spring Boot or any library that I use.  I would not expect to ever get more than release notes.  Conversion refactoring is up to me.

Comment: @duffymo backwards compatibility is hard, and there are occasionly valid reasons for a library to break it. If it does, helping users with the migration will ease the pain. But this comment thread is not the right place for this discussion.

Comment: I don't disagree that it's painful.  I'm pointing out that Spring Boot offers no such script.  I don't need instruction from you on how SO works.

Comment: Intellij already has refactoring shortcuts to do that, but it also has a systematic programmatic way (and with Groovy): https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/structural-search-and-replace.html#share_template

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a job for [OpenRewrite](https://docs.openrewrite.org/running-recipes/getting-started). Standard recipes, e.g., for renaming a package are available. You can also write your own recipes, which make use of a visitor pattern over a tree-based representation of your source code (which will preserve, e.g., indentation).

You can use Maven or Gradle to execute the rewrite.

For instance the change package configuration from the getting started page looks like this:

```
type: specs.openrewrite.org/v1beta/recipe
name: com.yourorg.VetToVeterinary
recipeList:
  - org.openrewrite.java.ChangePackage:
    oldPackageName: org.springframework.samples.petclinic.vet
    newPackageName: org.springframework.samples.petclinic.veterinary
```

Comment: Oh, i've never heard of OpenRewrite, but at quick glance this looks pretty much what I would be looking for (I'm not the original asker, so maybe they are looking for something different)!

Answer (score 2):

Not Groovy based (but then other answers suggesting "OpenRewrite" or "IntelliJ" aren't Groovy based either).

What OP is asking for is a [program transformation system (PTS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation) that will let him write custom transformation rules.  Most PTS system provide you with access to the target language AST... and you write custom rules by coding procedural visitors that clamber around the tree, matching and splicing individual tree nodes. Eclipse works like this; apparantly also OpenRewrite.

That's a clumsy way to do it, mostly because the details of the AST are voluminous and sort of arbitrary, and your tree-crawling code has to know all of this.  See [program_transforms on AST vs surface syntax](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/ProgramTransformation.html)  for more details.  Ideally you'd write transformations using the surface syntax of the programming language and let the PTS take care of doing the matching and replacement against the actual AST.

Our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html) will let you do this.  The transformations op wants do are coded like this:

```
Domain Java~v11; -- specifies which specific Java dialect grammar is relevant

rule rename_foo(p:access_path_prefix): access_path -> access_path
  = "\p foo.method2" -> "\p foo.method3";

rule rename_myMethod(p:access_path_prefix): access_path -> access_path
  = "\p myMethod" -> "\p your_method";

rule change_import_AnotherClassFromExternalPackage: import_statement -> import_statement
  = "import org.you.core.util.AnotherClassFromExternalPackage"
    -> "import com.me.core.util.AnotherClassFromExternalPackage";

ruleset my_patches = 
   { rename_foo, 
     rename_myMethod, 
     change_import_AnotherClassFromExternalPackage
   }
```

The `Domain` keyword tells DMS which precise grammar to use to parse the source text, including the specific dialect. (Java 6 is not the same as Java 11).

Individual rules are named (e.g., `rename_foo`). The parmeter list (e.g. `p:access_path_prefix`) allows one to specify a named piece of syntax (e.g., `p`) that can match an arbitrary tree of the syntax category (e.g., `access_path_prefix`).  Each rule specifies that it is a mapping `->` from one piece of syntax to another; for these rules, source and target syntax categories are the same (e.g. `access_path`).

Each rule also specifies the details of the mapping ( `= "*match*" -> "*replacement*"` ) where match and replacement are valid surface syntax patterns that match the source and target syntax categories respectively.  The reason for the quote marks is to separate the rule syntax from the source/target language syntax (e..g Java) inside the quotes. The match pattern `"\p foo.method2"` matches an arbitrary path prefix (a sequence of identifiers trailed by dots or a special case of empty, as defined by the Java grammar) followed by the end of the access_path `foo.method2` as op desired. The replacement pattern is that same access_path_prefix `p` followed by the changed end of access path `foo.method3`.

The `ruleset mypatches` collects the individual rules into a group that DMS can apply everywhere.

One can run a DMS RuleRewrite engine configured for Java~v11, point it at a legal Java file, and apply the `mypatches` ruleset to achieve what OP desires. DMS parses the file to build the AST, parses the rules to construct the ASTs necessary for matching, matches the rule ASTs and replaces ASTs where matches occur (so you don't have to do all this stuff with procedural tree hacking).  When complete, DMS regenerates the transformed source text, preserving indentation, comments, etc.

So you get a mechanical process for applying the rules of interest, with the rules being fairly easy to write because they use (Java) surface syntax rather than tree-climbing primitives.

These are rather simple examples.  We've used DMS to carry out massive rewrites across Java and C++, and even to translate COBOL to Java.

Comment: FYI: the `semdesigns.com` shows a certificate for `semanticdesigns.com` and even that is no longer valid, so I doubt many people are going to successfully follow that link.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thanks for the note.  We'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I would have an excel with columns like,

[image]

1. Use a library like Apache POI to read the Excel file and extract the required information (project name, package name, class name, method name, and field name).
2. Use a library like Eclipse JDT to parse the source code and build the AST.
3. Traverse the AST and identify the nodes that correspond to the specified classes, methods, and fields.
4. Apply the required modifications to the identified AST nodes.
5. Generate the modified source code from the updated AST.